# Executing pytest from GitBash

Tags: python, pytest

I have an issue executing pytest from GitBash.
In GitBash im located in directory of my pytest and .py file. Writing `pytest` in GitBash gives me `bash: pytest: command not found`. I know that i can execute pytest from the PyChamr's terminal, but it's not this comfortable to use as executed from Bash.
I looked in internet and found, that pytest installed in venv, this may cause some issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to either add the directory where `pytest` is located to your `PATH` environment variable or you need to specify the full path in the command. For GitBash, you can do this by editing the `.bashrc` file in your home directory.

Comment: I don't understant how to add the directory of pytest to the PATH. I need a specific command or smth? Thanks

Comment: @Kedow I suggest you google something like "PATH git bash" for more info.